# Loop function on Bash freezes my Raspberry Pi while executing xdotool commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi, xdotool

I have a rpi4 8gb that on the startup opens chromium and executes this Bash script

The idea is to refresh the browser every x random interval and execute some key strokes

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export XAUTHORITY=/home/sean/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:0

while true
do
    random=$(( $RANDOM % 1740 + 3540 )) #random number between 29 to 59 minutes
    sleep $random
    xdotool key F11  
    xdotool key "Ctrl+Shift+r" &
done
```

Sometimes I found that the system freezes, what could cause the problem?

Comment: How is this script called? Is it backgrounded? Obviously if you call it in the foreground, it will just sit there (appearing to freeze) for the entire `sleep` duration.

Comment: It's autorefresh_chromium.sh
What it freezes its the machine itself, so the raspberry pi doesn't work anymore and I have to unplug it. Apparently it should work fine, but there may be something that I'm missing that could cause the system freezes

Comment: Are you calling it from a crontab like the directions in the original forum post say [Chromium Auto Refresh](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=178206) (note: that way 5+ years ago)

Comment: Yes, it's working fine, the main problem would be the bash code itself. Something drains the memory to cause the crashes

Comment: My guess would be an issue (memory leak?) in `xdotool`. The bash is plane vanilla bash, so nothing unexpected. `RANDOM` will not exhaust the ransom pool, so no issues there. Never heard of `xdotool`, but that is the only unique part of your script.

Comment: That could be it! Despite the fact that it's a super interesting tool, it doesn't seem to be popular, therefore it could not be properly maintained

Comment: That's the only downside to finding the one "niche" tool that looks like the best thing since sliced bread, if it isn't actively maintained by a reasonably large community of developers -- you never know quite what you are getting -- unless you do a line-by-line through the source code (may as well write your own at that point, and if you find an issue on github, do a pull-request and submit the patched code) Let us know if you find an alternative.

Comment: `xdotool` is actually a fairly popular tool for X11 GUI automation; I doubt you will find any alternative which is more widely used.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `&` sign on the last line is what causes the freeze. However consider this alternative:

I recommend that instead of making an infinite loop (which could potentially freeze up your system in many ways), just assign it as a cronjob in 30min intervals.

this simplified script without loop should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
export XAUTHORITY=/home/sean/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:0
xdotool key F11  
xdotool key "Ctrl+Shift+r"
```

`crontab -e` (choose an editor example nano)

add this line at the end of the file: (runs script every hour:00 and hour:30)

`*/30 * * * * /home/sean/autorefresh_chromium.sh` add the correct path

`ctrl+S` to save

`ctrl+X` to exit

That's it. It will run in the background every 30min, even after reboots. The benefit is that this way the script refreshes the browser and exits, so it is not constantly sitting on your system and it cannot get stuck.

I also use xdotool, but not on a pi. I recommend to be cautious if you are running in headless mode, because without a monitor and other GUI components xdotool might not behave as expected. Considering that you refresh a webpage I guess you have GUI so it should be fine.